# Dataframe returning values in seperate columns instead of one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to make a new dataframe(df3)that has the values and index from 
another dataframe(df).When i pick the value from df into the df3, each value 
is added in seperate column instead of one column .

Here's what i did :

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=[df[6][3:270],index= [df[4][3:270]])

df3.columns = ['GDP in billions of chained 2009 dollars']

df3.index.rename('quarter', inplace = True)
```

This is the error i got :

> Length mismatch: Expected axis has 267 elements, new values have 1 elements

Comment: You should use `iloc` to index so it becomes `data=[df.iloc[3:270, 6],index= [df.iloc[3:270, 4]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   df3 = pd.DataFrame(df1.iloc[3:270, 6],index = [df1.iloc[3:270, 4]])
```

Comment: i'm getting this error :  IndexError: index out of bounds

Comment: index out of bounds meaning you are trying to access a row which is not available ..check how many rows are there in df